# First line of first paragraph after section/subsection is indented

Tags: sectioning, indentation, multicol

When writing an essay with the `article` class, the first line after a `section` or `subsection` has somewhere along the way become indented.

According to typographic standards (American standards, I believe?) the first line in a paragraph following a heading should not be indented. Somehow, my first lines have become indented.

I am using `input` to handle the text below a section, looking something like this:

```
\subsection{Section name}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\input{Sections/Text.tex}
\end{multicols}
```

As you can see, I am using the `multicol` package to enable multiple columns. The other packages (relevant to my problem) I am using are: `MinionPro`, `simplemargins` and `lettrine` (although I haven't implemented it in the text yet).

Is there something apparent that I've missed? Is there a package conflict here, perhaps? If the problem lies in the `multicols` package, is there a solution to my problem where I can keep my two-column-layout?

Comment: you will need to provide a minimal example to make it easier to get answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [multicol](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) manual (Section 2 - The User Interface, p. 2ff) offers a very simple solution.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
   \begin{multicols}{2}[\section{A Section title}]
     \blindtext
   \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Note that the [blindtext](http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext) package is only for creating dummy text thus not part of the solution.